# How to Limit the user to inputting a certain amount of characters each line. Characters must be ' . ' or ' * ' only

Tags: c#

Basically I need to take a certain amount of characters from the input depending on the dimensions of the game chosen by the user. For example user chooses 4 columns ; therefore only 4 characters are needed to store in array.

I've tried this but i dont know what method to put instead of 'Cols' or what i have to do for it to work.

```
var line = Cols.Lines.Select(i => i.Remove(Cols)).ToArray();
```

Comment: The user is inputting how many rows and columns he wishes to play the game with. For Example 4 rows, 4 columns.Using a for loop i managed to limit the amount of rows inputted but i need to limit the amount of columns now to input into an array.

Comment: What type is `Cols`, and what type is `Lines`? Where is the user input? Perhaps if you show the existing code where you get and process the user input, it would be easier to help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `i` is an array

```
var line = Cols.Lines.Select(i => i.Take(numberOfCols)).ToArray();
```

If `i` is a string

```
var line = Cols.Lines.Select(i => i.Substring(0, numberOfCols)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Yes but i cant set a definite number for it to take as it depends on the dimension of the game. So when you say i.Take(4) i need it to be i.Take(Cols).

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer to include a variable. I didn't use Cols to avoid confusion with the object at the start of the line.

Comment: Yes, what shall i change that object to for it to work? as its telling me that it does not exist in the current context.

Comment: `Cols` will probably be a variable that you declare. It could be a an array of strings, an array of arrays, or a `List<string>`. It probably depends how you're filling and using it.